# Calling Access Macro from VB.NET problems

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access

I call an Access macro from vb.net like so:

```
Acc.DoCmd.RunMacro("Macro1")
```

The Macro in Access has many OpenQuerys and Msgbox with a message saying "data done" at the end.

When I execute the macro from vb.net, it shows the data done message and then done. However, when I analyse the table's to see if data has been appended, it hasen't.

When I run the same macro from within Access, it works fine. It does show many messages like "You are about to run an append query that will modify data in your query" and I hit yes and does take slightly longer, but it does do it. 
In VB.NET, the only message I get is the final messagebox.

I have also tried:

```
Acc.SetOption("Confirm Action Queries", 0)
Acc.SetOption("Confirm Document Deletions", 0)
Acc.SetOption("Confirm Record Changes", 0)
```

before executing the macro from within VB.NET but to no avail. Still works the same.

Is there a way to fix it?

EDIT: My Access DB is mdb file

Comment: This looks like a terrible way of doing things. Why not just run the SQL commands directly, instead of mucking about with automating Access?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the UI messages in the macro:
*It does show many messages like "You are about to run an append query that will modify data in your query" and I hit yes*

There's an option in Access to suppress these confirmation queries, you'll want them suppressed in the .mdb file.  Looks like attempting to suppress them from VB isn't working.